# jQuery asort() or keep sorting after JSON encoding?

Tags: jquery, json, asort

I have a PHP array containing vehicle makes, like this :

```
array(
    5 => Audi,
    2 => Ford,
    1 => Opel,
    6 => Renault,
    9 => Volkswagen,
)
```

I get it with Ajax, returning JSON encoded array to my JS.
Problem is, the json_encoding automatically sort my array by key, so I get :

```
array(
    1 => Opel,
    2 => Ford,
    5 => Audi,
    6 => Renault,
    9 => Volkswagen,
)
```

How can I keep my array sorted ? Or re-sort in jQuery ?
Thank you

Comment: What is the actual JSON output? Assuming it's an object, then it cannot be sorted. You would need to use an array in that case.

Comment: Why are you not returning Audi at first index from PHP? Why Opel is coming at index one?

Comment: It's an object casted to an array. It works well, the issue is caused by the json_encode() who sort my array by keys, and not by values.
The first one is ordered by values ASC (result i want), but json_encode() sort it by keys ASC.

Answer (score 0):

Better you do it from PHP. Use [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) which doesn't maintain index association and then encode it as a JSON.

If possible you can return it as an associative array using [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). So that it will look something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [vehicle_makes] => Opel
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [vehicle_makes] => Audi
        )
    ...
)
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I forgot to tell that I need the keys because it's an ID.

Comment: So, steps : 
1. I have the first array (my wanted result). 
2. I do a json_encode() on it
3. I json_decode() it and the array is now ordered by keys instead of values.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I can't. This array is the result from a webservice call.